# What is meant exactly by the domains in this context and how can I simulate their size?

Tags: python, numerics, computational-physics, model

I was working on a problem from "Computational Physics using python: Chapter 17." The problem is concerned with simulating the thermodynamics behind the spin of electrons and the resulting change in energy and magnetization. The last part of the problem asks for making a graph for the average domain size versus temperature. I'm familiar with magnetic domains, but I'm not really sure how to simulate them.

My initial thinking was domains here is similar to measuring how many neighbouring electrons have the same spin. So, I though about writing a code that checks every electron in the configuration and counts the average size of domains by checking whether they are similar or not. I tried it but didn't work out as I want. Does anyone have any suggestions?

My 1D Ising model:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Defining the initial spin of all N particles of the system 
def initialstate(N):   
    state = 2*np.random.randint(2, size=(1,N))-1 
    return state

# Defining the monte carlo random flipping of the spins
def mcmove(config, beta):
    for i in range(N):
        b = np.random.randint(0, N) # what spin we try to flip (a random spin)
        s =  config[0,b] # initial spin of the spin we will try to flip
        nb = config[0,(b+1)%N] + config[0,(b-1)%N]
        cost = 2*s*nb
        if cost < 0:
            s *= -1 # flip the spin
        elif rand() < np.exp(-cost*beta):
            s *= -1 # flip the spin
        #otherwise we don't flip the spin
        config[0,b] = s # new state (with s either flipped or not) 
    return config

# Calculating the energy of the system
def calcEnergy(config):
    energy = 0
    for i in range(N):
        S = config[0,i]
        nb = config[0,(i+1)%N] + config[0,(i-1)%N]
        #print nb
        energy += -nb*S
    return energy/2.

# Calculating the magnetization of the system
def calcMag(config):
    mag = np.sum(np.sum(config))
    return mag

nt      = 2**6        # number of temperature points
N       = 2**4        # size of the lattice, N
eqSteps = 2**10       # number of MC sweeps for equilibration
mcSteps = 2**10       # number of MC sweeps for calculation

n1, n2  = 1.0/(mcSteps*N*1), 1.0/(mcSteps*mcSteps*N*1)  

T=np.linspace(.2, 2, nt)

Energy       = np.zeros(nt);   Magnetization  = np.zeros(nt)
SpecificHeat = np.zeros(nt);   Susceptibility = np.zeros(nt)


for m in range(len(T)):
    
    config = initialstate(N)
    iT=1.0/T[m]; iT2=iT*iT; # beta = 1/(k_B*T)
    
    for l in range(eqSteps):         # equilibrate
        mcmove(config, iT)           # Monte Carlo moves


    #Calculate quantities post equilibriation
    E1 = M1 = E2 = M2 = 0
    for i in range(mcSteps):
        mcmove(config, iT)           
        Ene = calcEnergy(config)     # calculate the energy
        Mag = calcMag(config)        # calculate the magnetisation

        E1 = E1 + Ene                 #Cumulative energy 
        M1 = M1 + Mag
        M2 = M2 + Mag*Mag 
        E2 = E2 + Ene*Ene

        Energy[m]         = n1*E1     #Weighing for MC averages. 
        Magnetization[m]  = n1*M1
        SpecificHeat[m]   = (n1*E2 - n2*E1*E1)*iT2
        Susceptibility[m] = (n1*M2 - n2*M1*M1)*iT2


f = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8)); # plot the calculated values    

sp =  f.add_subplot(1, 2, 1 );
plt.plot(T, Energy, 'o', color="#348ABD", label='simulation');
plt.plot(T, -np.tanh(1.0/T), color="#A60628", lw=2,label='analytical')
plt.xlabel("Temperature (T)", fontsize=20);
plt.ylabel("Energy / spin ", fontsize=20); plt.legend(fontsize=16)


sp =  f.add_subplot(1, 2, 2 );
plt.plot(T, Magnetization, 'o', color="#348ABD", label='simulation');
#plt.plot(T, (1.0/T**2)*(np.cosh(1.0/T))**(-2), color="#A60628", lw=2,label='analytical')
plt.xlabel("Temperature (T)", fontsize=20); #plt.ylim([-10, -2])
plt.ylabel("Magnetization / spin ", fontsize=20);  plt.legend(fontsize=16)
```

A snippet of the code I tried but always gave me a size of zero:

```
domain = 0
for i in range(len(T)):
  for i in range(N):
     s  = config[0, i]
     if s == s+1:
       domain += 1
```

Comment: I would try to calculate the autocorrelation function for the spin; perhaps that's all what's needed there.